# Implementing sign a document option without send notification email to signer

Tags: docusignapi

I am trying to implement sign a document option in my application.

[image]

It is working perfectly but during the process it sends email to signer to review document (which doesn't happen when created via DocuSign UI). How I can stop this review document email from sending to signer.

Here what I am doing in my code

1. Creating envelope

   ```
       try
       {
           EnvelopeDefinition envDef = new EnvelopeDefinition();
           envDef.EmailSubject = selectedFileList[0].subject;
           envDef.Documents = new List<Document>();
           foreach (var file in selectedFileList)
           {
               envDef.Documents.Add(getDocument(file.localPath, file.fullFileName, file.extension, file.number.ToString(), file.version.ToString(), file.databaseName));
           }

           Signer signer = new Signer();
           signer.Email = signerEmail;
           signer.Name = signerName;
           signer.RecipientId = "1";
           envDef.Recipients = new Recipients();
           envDef.Recipients.Signers = new List<Signer>();
           envDef.Recipients.Signers.Add(signer);
           envDef.Status = "sent";

           EnvelopesApi envelopesApi = new EnvelopesApi(config);
           var response = await Task.Run(() => { return envelopesApi.CreateEnvelopeWithHttpInfo(accountId, envDef); });

           EnvelopeSummary envelopeSummary = response.Data;
           responseHeaders = response.Headers;

       }
       catch (Exception ex)
       {
           throw ex;
       }
   ```
2. Creating receipent view

   ```
           EnvelopesApi envelopesApi = new EnvelopesApi(apiConfig);

           RecipientViewRequest viewRequest = new RecipientViewRequest();
           viewRequest.UserName = signerName;
           viewRequest.Email = signerEmail;
           viewRequest.RecipientId = "1";
           viewRequest.AuthenticationMethod = "email";
           viewRequest.ReturnUrl = returnUrl;
           //viewRequest.ClientUserId = apiConfig;

           var view = envelopesApi.CreateRecipientView(accountId, envelopeId, viewRequest);
           var url = view.Url;
   ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add this code in your app:

```
var textCustomFields = new List<TextCustomField>();
var textCustomField = new TextCustomField { Name = "AppName", Value = "DocuSignIt" };
textCustomFields.Add(textCustomField);
envDef.CustomFields.TextCustomFields = textCustomFields;
```

This should tell DocuSign not to send the email.

Comment: Hi Inbar, Thank you so muck for your quick response. Yes, your code worked. Only one modification I had to do to make it work is, I had to create CustomFields for envelope defination object. So, I change the last line to `envDef.CustomFields = new CustomFields(null, textCustomFields);`

Comment: Hi @Inbar, Some reason this change doesn't work with production account. Do you have any idea why it is work sandbox account not production?

Comment: what do you mean by "don't work" you do the same exact thing in production and the result is what?

Comment: I mean in production it is sedning review email to signer.

Comment: Apel, I just found out this code I shared with you only works in the sandbox :( I'm sorry, I was not aware of this limitation, I think it's new. I wonder if you can try Larry's option of ClientUserId in prod? does it still not show the "sign and return" option?

Comment: Yes, I tried adding ClientUserId still we receiving review email. Do you know when this code will be implemented in production?

Comment: are you doing both? can you share your latest code?

Comment: No, I am not doing both. Because of characters limit I can't post code in the comment. I have uploaded my code in here https://www.imanageshare-au.com/pd/9Iw7OPoHEie

Comment: well, one last thing you can try, but not sure it will work , there's a URL parameter like this - &disable_cc_for_selfsign=true, so you can try to add it with false, and see if that overrides it. This disable_cc_for_selfsign would not show the "Sign and Return" dialog, so maybe setting it to false can help, not sure

Comment: To which url you want me add this query parameter. Is it recipient view url?

Comment: exactly, the one you use to show embedded signing to user

Answer (score 0):

Setting the `ClientUserId` attribute value for a recipient also marks the recipient to not receive the email invitation to sign.

Setting `ClientUserId` is the recommended approach for embedded signing.

The value of the `ClientUserId` attribute also acts as a connection between the authentication that your application has done and the signing ceremony which enables the person to sign the documents.

Comment: Thanks Lerry for your response. Yes, I have tried ClientUserId before and it works but some reason after complete signing, UI doesn't display Sing and Return dialog.